# I am finding it difficult to understand this C Code

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void graph(int count);

int main() {
    int value;
    value = 2;
    while (value <= 64) {
        graph(value);
        printf("Value is %d\n", value);
        value = value * 2;
    }
    return (0);
}

void graph(int count) {
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < count; x = x + 1)
        putchar('*');
    putchar('\n');
}
```

The above is my code. I am learning C and as a beginner I am finding it quite difficult to understand that code. My questions are:

- What does int count do ? Is is user defined or system inbuilt?
- Why is there value that we declared inside graph()? Does it act like an input we gave ?
- And in graph()  or anywhere there is no initial value for count but why is it used and for what ?

Comment: BTW if this is C, please don't tag as c++

Comment: C++ is a successor of C so just in case if anyone happened help me !

Comment: *I will be grateful to you if you elaborate every piece of the code.* Unfortunately, that's not what this site is for. Ideally you would get a basic grasp of the language and ask about concrete problems you encounter when writing actual code.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I don't mind elaborating on the three points he had trouble understanding.  We all start somewhere.

Comment: @Eric, yup, I saw that. However, I still believe questions about structural programming basics (here functions and arguments, mostly) are off-topic for Stack Overflow. But go ahead, it's not like your answer is harmful :)

Comment: sheesh guys. For once a begginer comes with a code sample that compiles, fits in a single screen and relatively well defined questions but you still shower him w/ downvotes...

Comment: @hugomg, -2 is far from "showering", and *I will be grateful to you if you elaborate every piece of the code* is not a well-defined question.

Comment: `+1` from me.  I had dumber questions when I was learning C, and there was no Stack Overflow at the time.

Comment: @mistgeek: C++ may be a successor to C, but that doesn't mean it *behaves* like C in all cases.  The two languages have diverged quite a bit over the years, and should be considered completely different at this point.  There's plenty of legal C code that is *not* legal C++ code, and what is legal may not have the same meaning.

Comment: @JohnBode Okay I'm sorry !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does `int count` do ? Is is user defined or system inbuilt?

`int count` specifies that the function `graph` takes a single parameter, which is of type `int`.  That is part of the C language.

> Why is there value that we declared inside graph()? Does it act like an input we gave ?

I'm not sure exactly what you mean here.  The input parameter `count` is used to specify how many times the `for` loop is run.  `int x` is a variable of type `int` that only exists (is scoped to) the function `graph`.

That means `count` inside of `graph()` will have the value your variable `value` has in the line where `graph()` is called:

```
graph(value);
```

`value` starts at 2 because of the line

```
value = 2;
```

and gets doubled each time through the `while` loop until it is 64 by the lines

```
while (value <= 64) // Checks whether or not to end the while loop
```

and

```
value = value * 2; // Doubles the previous value
```

> And in graph() or anywhere there is no initial value for count but why is it used and for what ?

`x` is initialized in the `for` loop.  That is where it gets the initial value.  If you look at the line

```
for(x=0;x<count;x=x+1)
```

The part

```
x=0
```

initializes the `for` loop.  Typically a loop counter will get its initial value in that part of the `for` statement.

Comment: Yes thanks for catching that.  Corrected it (also if you have enough reputation, it would be fine to edit it yourself).

Comment: uhh guys i didnt get anything . Take me as a complete beginner please?

Comment: Complete beginner??? I think you need very little basics to get this into mind. And you cant get it even after explanation. Feeling pity

Comment: @mistgeek: I added some more detail for you.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

> What does int count do ? Is is user defined or system inbuilt?

`int` is a keyword defined by the C language (you can even see that the syntax highlighter draws it in blue while the user defined stuff is in black. It serves to declare the type of a variable. When you do

```
int x;
```

You are declaring a new variable that contains an integer value. Yuo can get the value of a variable by using its name and you can assign a new value to a variable with the `=` operator

```
x = 10
```

or with the `++` operator

```
x++  //this adds one to the value of x
```

> Why is there value that we declared inside graph()? Does it act like an input we gave ?

graph is a function / subroutine. The variables defined inside the parenthesis are arguments to the subroutines.

> And in graph() or anywhere there is no initial value for count but why is it used and for what ?

SUbroutine arguments are initialized by whoever calls the subroutine.  In this case, `graph(value)`, in the main function).

Answer (score 2):

A general C function is defined as:

```
return_type function_name(parameter_1, parameter_2, ...)
{
  local_variables

  function_logic

  return return_value
}
```

Parameters are passed into your function so that when you call graph(value), count is set to value.

Essentially, your loop is calling graph(2), graph(4), graph(8)... which sets count to 2, 4, 8...

For loop syntax is:

```
for(initialization; condition; increment) {
  loop_logic
}
```

The loop body executes repeatedly until the condition is no longer true.
So x is initialized at zero, incremented by 1 (x++ is the same as x = x+1) until the condition is x is greater than or equal to count.

Essentially, this means that your graph function is printing out 'count' number of *, followed by a newline, which moves the cursor to the next line.

This is the output of your program.

```
Value is 2
**
Value is 4
****
Value is 8
********
```

and so on.

I would advise looking up some general programming tutorials before delving into more complex code.

Answer (score 1):

> What does int count do ?

In the line

```
void graph(int count)
```

`int count` declares `count` as a *parameter* or argument to the function `graph` of type `int`.  That means that any code that *calls* the `graph` function must provide an integer argument.  You can see this in the `main` function in the call

```
graph(value);
```

The value in `value` is copied to the parameter `count` when the `graph` function is called.

> Is is user defined or system inbuilt?

In this case, it's user-defined.

> Why is there value that we declared inside graph()? Does it act like an input we gave ?
>   And in graph() or anywhere there is no initial value for count but why is it used and for what ?

The variable `x` is used to control the following loop:

```
for(x=0;x<count;x=x+1)
    putchar('*');
```

This shows the order in which the elements of the loop are being executed:

```
for ( /* 1 */ x = 0; /* 2 */ x < count; /* 4 */ x = x + 1 )
  /* 3 */ putchar('*');
```

The logic basically reads as follows:

1. Assign 0 to x
2. Compare the value stored in `x` to the value passed to the function in `count`.  If `x` is less than `count`, go to step 3, otherwise go to step 5.
3. Write the `*` character to standard output.
4. Add 1 to x, then go to step 2.
5. Exit loop.

The whole program draws lines of `*` characters, where each line is twice the length of the previous line:

```
**
Value is 2
****
Value is 4
********
Value is 8
****************
Value is 16
...
```

The `graph` function is responsible for drawing each line of `*` characters.  `main` calls `graph` with the number of characters to draw (`graph(value)`), starting with 2 characters, and doubling that number until it's greater than 64.  Then it calls `printf` to display the value of the `value` variable (say *that* three times fast).

Answer (score 0):

1.int count takes argument from  value (its a FUNCTION CALL-in the first run the value is 2)
-- It's user defined . U can write any name like (int count/ int xyz/...)

2.Yeah ! it acts like input. Here we gave the 'value' term assigned to '2' .

3.That 2 will be copied into count. and proceed with the function procedure inside graph function like       -  ..printing '*' iterratively.

.. initial value of count is nothing but the value u have assigned for the term 'value' .here it's 2
If u assign the value term to 4 then count will take the value 4

Google and learn about basic function calls in c.

---hope u got some clarification---

Comment: I dont think l33tsp33k iz gonna help, cuz.

Comment: thank you man i appericiate it :)